# Connecting Android to Fedora to browse the web

Tags: linux, tethering

I have bought an Android phone *Spice MI-270*. I wanted to connect the phone to Linux *Fedora* so that I can browse the web using the services provided on my SIM card. How can I connect the Android phone to Linux *Fedora* to use the Internet ?

Comment: Why do you need to connect to Fedora to use Internet from your SIM card?

Comment: @ roxan i want to use internet on my laptop

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the internet connection your Android device provides to access the internet when working on your laptop, this is called [Tethering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering) (this Wikipedia article gives you closer information). The followint Q&A gives you some closer information on this topic:

[Use 3G connection on my Android in Ubuntu](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15734/use-3g-connection-on-my-android-in-ubuntu)

Though the title mentions Ubuntu, the solution provided there explicitly states to also support Fedora -- and it should work via USB cable.

Starting with Froyo (Android 2.2), your device can also directly act as a Wifi Hotspot (just check in the setup under *Wireless & Networks*) -- which of course requires your laptop to support Wifi (but which laptop does not?). When running into trouble with this, you might want to check this Q&A:

[Tethering an Android 2.2.1 (Froyo) using Wifi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11158/tethering-an-android-2-2-1-froyo-using-wifi)

---

If your question is rather the other way around: Your laptop having internet, and you want to use that connection from your Android, this is called *Reverse tethering*. In this case check:

[Connect Android device as wifi adapter to a PC to create an ad-hoc network](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/connect-android-device-as-wifi-adapter-to-a-pc-to-create-an-ad-hoc-network)

More on reverse tethering you can find checking the [questions tagged reverse-tether](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether).